# Excel 2003 VBA code works when stepping through but not when run fully

Tags: excel, vba

I found and amended Excel VBA code to open a webpage and then open a linked file.

It works when I step through it but when it runs fully it doesn't open the file.

```
Sub CallWebPage()

Dim URL As String
Dim ieApp As Object
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieForm As Object
Dim ieObj As Object
Dim objColl As Collection

URL = "http://sdrk3020v/mi_toolbox/default.asp?query_name=spBUS_GCR_AllSchemes&app_id=2&FileType=csv&btnRunQuery=Run+query"

Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ieApp.Visible = True
ieApp.navigate URL

While ieApp.Busy
    'wait...
Wend

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
For Each ele In ieApp.Document.getelementsbytagname("a")

    If ele.innertext = "query_1" Then
        DoEvents
        ele.Click
    End If
Next

ieApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works fine .. I just updated the URL and changed the `InnerText`.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat - I have no idea what goes on with your code

With that caveat, given that your code goes out into the real world to open a web page, I'm guessing that the difference between success and failure is something to do with `time`.

IE When you step though the code things are given enough time to complete so that when the code to click the link gets run everything is perfectly set up so it all works.

But when you run it at full speed something is not happening fast enough behind the scenes, so that the link is not ready (or exists) when it comes time for your code to click on it.  I have no idea why this could be, but given that things like AJAX can load web pages asynchronously it would not surprise me that your web page doesn't instantly spring to life.

This sort of thing is called a `Race Condition` (multiple parts of code are racing to see who gets there first) and the solution is to figure out how to stop this from occurring.  This could mean finding some status that says the web page is 100% really truly loaded (the best scenario), or as dumb as putting in a time delay at a critical point that allows for being 99.999% longer than the worst case setup time  (which is really bad and can lead to horrible to diagnose bugs later on when you hit that 0.0001% situation - as you know you have fixed the race condition with your delay)

Answer (score 1):

Try using DoEvents this will stop the excel from running until the background processes are completed. This might help u solve your issue

Regards
Umesh